# Lists in a parent list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I run through a list of objects which contains lists and I will merge all these list in a new list. 
I have tried to do it with Java 8 but with no success.

```
final List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Iterator<SchedulePresence> iterator = existingSchedulePresences.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    final SchedulePresence schedulePresence = iterator.next();
    final List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> sics = schedulePresence.getScheduleIntervalContainersForDate(dateTimeToNavigate, false,
        false);
    scheduleIntervalContainers.addAll(sics);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap` exists for this purpose :

```
List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers =
    existingSchedulePresences.stream()
                             .flatMap(sp->sp.getScheduleIntervalContainersForDate(dateTimeToNavigate, false, false).stream())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:

If `existingSchedulePresences` may contain `null` elements, you can filter them, as Alexis suggested :

```
List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers =
    existingSchedulePresences.stream()
                             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                             .flatMap(sp->sp.getScheduleIntervalContainersForDate(dateTimeToNavigate, false, false).stream())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to handle it when **sp** is null?

Comment: @user3318489 yes, you can change the lambda expression inside `flatMap` to sp->sp!=null?sp.getScheduleIntervalContainersForDate(dateTimeToNavigate, false, false).stream():Stream.empty()

Comment: @Eran You'd better add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` just before.